# mysql duplicate rows and replace

Tags: mysql, replace, duplicates

I have, perhaps, 180 entries in my mysql table.  I still have many rows to insert but I will eventually need to add an additional column called "style" which will have two options.  First off I'll need to put an option for the first couple hundred entries I already have - and next I'll need to duplicate those same entries except with option 2 as "style".  My ultimate question is how will I achieve duplicating these rows quickly (preferably with a simple query), and second how to duplicate those same rows but with a different option for "style".
Thank you

Comment: Basically I'd like to duplicate several hundred rows, then change the value of a specific column for those rows.

Comment: your primery key is autoincremental? can you add the description of your table to the question.

Comment: yes my primary key is auto incremental.  Perhaps this would be a good opportunity to describe to me how to include a representation of my table.  I see many people doing it as: ************** (sorry that's so vague but I hope you get my point).

Comment: See i edit your question and there i show you how to, there are already 2 answers and thats the way you resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an insert-select statement.

To just duplicate the rows:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable
WHERE  <some condition>
```

To duplicate with a different style:

```
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT col1, col2, 'someString' AS style
FROM   mytable
WHERE  <some condition>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-- set first option on all rows
UPDATE mytable 
   SET style = 'first option' ;
```

It's easier if you don't do a separate INSERT and a separate UPDATE; just insert the rows you want. You can supply a literal value for the `style` in the SELECT statement, and that value will be inserted.

```
-- replicate to a second set of rows with different option
INSERT INTO mytable (a,b,c,style)
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c, 'different option' AS style
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.style = 'first option' ;
```

Otherwise, if you replicate the rows, including the `style`, you'll need to differentiate between which rows to update, and which rows are not to be updated. (There's not enough information provided in the question to give you a recommendation on that.) With an auto_increment `id` column, you could get the max value of the `id` column, do the `insert ... select`, and get the max value again. That would give you the range of `id` values of the rows that were just inserted.

But, it would be easier and more efficient just to insert the rows as you need them, without running a separate UPDATE.